# Closing database using greenDao

Tags: android, database, orm, greendao

What is the best way to close (and reopen) da Database using greenDao ORM?

```
daoMaster.getDatabase().close()
```

or

```
daoSession.getDatabase().close()
```

and how to reopen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answere:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/greendao/close/greendao/tL4SPjOv7tA/JnBRRAqtORwJ

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
private SQLiteDatabase db; //Global Variable.
```

Initialize your helper and SQLiteDatabase in onResume method.

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this,"YourDBName",null);
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

close Database onPause

```
db.close();
```